# How can I change Laravel Policy response status code?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I'm using Laravel 9

I want to prevent User to view another User personal information.
This is my Policy method

```php
public function viewUser(User $user, User $model)
{
    return $user->id === $model->id;
}
```

and this is Controller method

```php
public function show(User $user)
{
    $this->authorize('viewUser', $user);
    return view('users.show', compact('user'));
}
```

It shows 403 as expected

But I want to change status code to 404 like this

```php
public function viewUser(User $user, User $model)
{
    return $user->id === $model->id
            ? Response::allow()
            : Response::deny(code: 404);
}
```

And it's still shows 403 not 404. What am I doing wrong with the Policy? I know I can change response using another approach but my question about Laravel Policies itself.

Route

```php
Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['auth'],
    'prefix' => 'users/{user}',
    'as' => 'users.',
], function () {
    Route::get('/', [UserController::class, 'show'])->name('show');
});
```

Comment: I don't quite see why you are doing this, but a "hackish" way would be to just `if ($user->id !== $model->id) { abort(404); } return true;`...

Comment: That being said, there is probably a better way to alter the response status code for failed authorization.

Comment: @KurtFriars Thanks for your reply! I know there are plenty of other options but I'm doing this because Laravel [said](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#policy-responses) you can do this :)

Comment: And do the custom messages in the response come through? It might still be overriding the code back to 403 down the line?

Comment: Yes message come through. I guess somewhere deep it checks for exception type and overrride status code while keeping message. It make sense not to thow AuthorizationException with 404 status code, but why is it even an option then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `app\Exceptions\Handler.php` in the `render()` method you can define what should be done when `X` Exception is thrown. That being said, adding below piece of code should do the trick for you:

```
if ($exception instanceof AuthorizationException) {
    $exception = new NotFoundHttpException;
}

return parent::render($request, $exception);
```

What it does is basically checking if the Exception that is thrown is an AuthorizationException (which policies in Laravel throw) and if that is the case, throw a new NotFoundHttpException (`404`). This will however change any and all AuthorizationExceptions to a 404, which is probably not wanted behaviour.

---

Update:

After digging I found a [closed proposal for returning 404](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/964).

Personally I feel that a policy should not return anything but a 403 status code, since that is the correct code, something is forbidden. Returning a 404 would not be correct since the policy does not handle X resource not found.

If you'd really want you could change the `Handler.php`. I feel like this is not the correct way to use policies however, but that's beside the point.

A user in above mentioned closed proposel used request parameters to check if the route belonged to a certain type, i.e. product and returned a 404 instead of 403. Maybe this can be applied to your use case aswell, check it out [here](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/964#issuecomment-540542230). Hope I've been thorough and it maybe helps.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that even an option! But does this will override every AuthorizationException? Cause I need to do it only once - I still need 403 in another cases

Comment: Right, but this would make all 403s into 404s. Definitely another option, but you have to go all in.

Comment: Well yes it would override them all. I currently don't know of any other way of doing this. You could however try @KurtFriars 's "hacky" approach.

Comment: However what I am wondering about is, why would you need this? You could just not show any personal information. I don't know if you read the docs but maybe [this](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#authorizing-actions-via-gates) helps.

Comment: Authorize method under the hood calls `Gate` methods if I'm not wrong. Yes I can do it with single line like `abort_if(auth()->user()->cannot('viewUser', $user), 404);` in my controller or create middleware with the same result. I just wonder what am I doing wrong with the policies. I guess the main reason behind it NOT to allow user show any other status for Authorization Exception but 403 (for semantic and correct response reasons) and that is why it overrides it.

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong really, however a policy is used to determine if a user is authorized. Returning 403 would make the most sense, 404 is to be honest just an incorrect response code for a policy.

Comment: @geertjanknapen I think you're doing this wrong should be the accepted answer in this case :) Yeah it makes sense to keep it 403 in a Policy and I should use another approach. Thanks for your help

Comment: You may edit your answer with extra lines something like "Why you should keep 403 status in a Policy", I'll accept it

Comment: I did some more digging and found some more information. Will update answer.

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka This closely resembles what you want to achieve, maybe it's useful: https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/964#issuecomment-789183384

Answer (score 2):

Since Laravel 9.20 it can be achieved with `denyAsNotFound` method - link to [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#customising-policy-response-status)

```php
public function viewUser(User $user, User $model)
{
     return $user->id === $model->id ?
            $this->allow() :
            $this->denyAsNotFound();
}
```

or more universal way with `denyWithStatus()`

```php
public function viewUser(User $user, User $model)
{
     return $user->id === $model->id ?
            $this->allow() :
            $this->denyWithStatus(404);
}
```